# GCP: error while creating image

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, ubuntu-16.04

I am making an image from a ubuntu vmdk virtual disk. but I am getting an error

The error:

```
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/compute-image-tools/gce_vm_image_import:release" failed: exit status 1
```

Full log:

```
starting build "b7070021-27a6-4702-8ec7-2b7bc2defde0"
FETCHSOURCE
BUILD
Pulling image: gcr.io/compute-image-tools/gce_vm_image_import:release
release: Pulling from compute-image-tools/gce_vm_image_import
9ff2acc3204b: Already exists
69e2f037cdb3: Already exists
df9954cc225a: Pulling fs layer
0f9ee8855661: Pulling fs layer
0f9ee8855661: Verifying Checksum
0f9ee8855661: Download complete
df9954cc225a: Verifying Checksum
df9954cc225a: Download complete
df9954cc225a: Pull complete
0f9ee8855661: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:083b7cd9d89d4238ff94d7da6e15d238d57dc9b715dbccb850926dca84daad41
Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/compute-image-tools/gce_vm_image_import:release
gcr.io/compute-image-tools/gce_vm_image_import:release
[import-and-translate]: 2020-01-29T18:42:40Z Validating workflow
[import-and-translate]: 2020-01-29T18:42:40Z Validating step "import"
[import-and-translate.import]: 2020-01-29T18:42:40Z Validating step "setup-disks"
[import-and-translate.import]: 2020-01-29T18:42:41Z Validating step "import-virtual-disk"
[import-and-translate.import]: 2020-01-29T18:42:41Z Validating step "wait-for-signal"
[import-and-translate.import]: 2020-01-29T18:42:41Z Validating step "cleanup"
[import-and-translate]: 2020-01-29T18:42:41Z Validating step "translate"
[import-and-translate.translate]: 2020-01-29T18:42:41Z Validating step "translate-disk"
[import-and-translate.translate.translate-disk]: 2020-01-29T18:42:41Z Validating step "setup-disk"
[import-and-translate.translate.translate-disk]: 2020-01-29T18:42:41Z Validating step "translate-disk-inst"
[import-and-translate.translate.translate-disk]: 2020-01-29T18:42:41Z Validating step "wait-for-translator"
[import-and-translate.translate.translate-disk]: 2020-01-29T18:42:41Z Validating step "delete-instance"
[import-and-translate.translate]: 2020-01-29T18:42:41Z Validating step "create-image"
[import-and-translate]: 2020-01-29T18:42:42Z Validating step "cleanup"
[import-and-translate]: 2020-01-29T18:42:42Z Validation Complete
[import-and-translate]: 2020-01-29T18:42:42Z Cloud Build ID: b7070021-27a6-4702-8ec7-2b7bc2defde0
[import-and-translate]: 2020-01-29T18:42:42Z Workflow Project: plex-266213
[import-and-translate]: 2020-01-29T18:42:42Z Workflow Zone: europe-west3-c
[import-and-translate]: 2020-01-29T18:42:42Z Workflow GCSPath: gs://plex-266213-daisy-bkt-europe-west3/
[import-and-translate]: 2020-01-29T18:42:42Z Daisy scratch path: https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/plex-266213-daisy-bkt-europe-west3/daisy-import-and-translate-20200129-18:42:40-0tnps
[import-and-translate]: 2020-01-29T18:42:42Z Uploading sources
[import-and-translate]: 2020-01-29T18:42:43Z Running workflow
[import-and-translate]: 2020-01-29T18:42:43Z Running step "import" (IncludeWorkflow)
[import-and-translate.import]: 2020-01-29T18:42:43Z Running step "setup-disks" (CreateDisks)
[import-and-translate.import.setup-disks]: 2020-01-29T18:42:43Z CreateDisks: Creating disk "disk-importer-import-and-translate-import-0tnps".
[import-and-translate.import.setup-disks]: 2020-01-29T18:42:43Z CreateDisks: Creating disk "temp-translation-disk-0tnps".
[import-and-translate.import.setup-disks]: 2020-01-29T18:42:43Z CreateDisks: Creating disk "disk-import-scratch-0tnps".
[import-and-translate.import]: 2020-01-29T18:42:46Z Step "setup-disks" (CreateDisks) successfully finished.
[import-and-translate.import]: 2020-01-29T18:42:46Z Running step "import-virtual-disk" (CreateInstances)
[import-and-translate.import.import-virtual-disk]: 2020-01-29T18:42:46Z CreateInstances: Creating instance "inst-importer-import-and-translate-import-0tnps".
[import-and-translate.import]: 2020-01-29T18:42:53Z Step "import-virtual-disk" (CreateInstances) successfully finished.
[import-and-translate.import]: 2020-01-29T18:42:53Z Running step "wait-for-signal" (WaitForInstancesSignal)
[import-and-translate.import.import-virtual-disk]: 2020-01-29T18:42:53Z CreateInstances: Streaming instance "inst-importer-import-and-translate-import-0tnps" serial port 1 output to https://storage.cloud.google.com/plex-266213-daisy-bkt-europe-west3/daisy-import-and-translate-20200129-18:42:40-0tnps/logs/inst-importer-import-and-translate-import-0tnps-serial-port1.log
[import-and-translate.import.wait-for-signal]: 2020-01-29T18:42:53Z WaitForInstancesSignal: Instance "inst-importer-import-and-translate-import-0tnps": watching serial port 1, SuccessMatch: "ImportSuccess:", FailureMatch: ["ImportFailed:" "WARNING Failed to download metadata script" "Worker instance terminated"] (this is not an error), StatusMatch: "Import:".
[import-and-translate.import.wait-for-signal]: 2020-01-29T18:43:03Z WaitForInstancesSignal: Instance "inst-importer-import-and-translate-import-0tnps": StatusMatch found: "Import: Copied image from gs://plexforubuntu/Ubuntu 64-bit.vmdk to /daisy-scratch/Ubuntu 64-bit.vmdk:"
[import-and-translate.import.wait-for-signal]: 2020-01-29T18:43:03Z WaitForInstancesSignal: Instance "inst-importer-import-and-translate-import-0tnps": StatusMatch found: "Import: Importing /daisy-scratch/Ubuntu 64-bit.vmdk of size 0GB to temp-translation-disk-0tnps in projects/935575348440/zones/europe-west3-c."
[import-and-translate.import.wait-for-signal]: 2020-01-29T18:43:03Z WaitForInstancesSignal: Instance "inst-importer-import-and-translate-import-0tnps": StatusMatch found: "Import: <serial-output key:'target-size-gb' value:'0'>"
[import-and-translate.import.wait-for-signal]: 2020-01-29T18:43:03Z WaitForInstancesSignal: Instance "inst-importer-import-and-translate-import-0tnps": StatusMatch found: "Import: <serial-output key:'source-size-gb' value:'1'>"
[import-and-translate.import.wait-for-signal]: 2020-01-29T18:43:03Z WaitForInstancesSignal: Instance "inst-importer-import-and-translate-import-0tnps": StatusMatch found: "Import: <serial-output key:'import-file-format' value:''>"
[import-and-translate.import.wait-for-signal]: 2020-01-29T18:43:03Z WaitForInstancesSignal: Instance "inst-importer-import-and-translate-import-0tnps": StatusMatch found: "Import: error: (0.00/100%)#015qemu-img: Could not open '\\''/daisy-scratch/Ubuntu 64-bit.vmdk'\\'': Could not open '\\''/daisy-scratch/Ubuntu 64-bit-s001.vmdk'\\'': No such file or directory '"
[import-and-translate.import.wait-for-signal]: 2020-01-29T18:43:03Z WaitForInstancesSignal: Instance "inst-importer-import-and-translate-import-0tnps": StatusMatch found: "Import: error: (0.00/100%)#015qemu-img: Could not open '/daisy-scratch/Ubuntu 64-bit.vmdk': Could not open '/daisy-scratch/Ubuntu 64-bit-s001.vmdk': No such file or directory "
[import-and-translate]: 2020-01-29T18:43:03Z Error running workflow: step "import" run error: step "wait-for-signal" run error: WaitForInstancesSignal FailureMatch found for "inst-importer-import-and-translate-import-0tnps": "ImportFailed: Failed to decode image file. When importing a VMDK disk image, ensure that you specify the VMDK disk image file, rather than its text descriptor file. In some virtual machine managers, given a text descriptor called <disk.vmdk>, the disk image file would be called <disk-flat.vmdk>.'"
[import-and-translate]: 2020-01-29T18:43:03Z Serial-output value -> target-size-gb:0
[import-and-translate]: 2020-01-29T18:43:03Z Serial-output value -> source-size-gb:1
[import-and-translate]: 2020-01-29T18:43:03Z Serial-output value -> import-file-format:
[import-and-translate]: 2020-01-29T18:43:03Z Workflow "import-and-translate" cleaning up (this may take up to 2 minutes).
[import-and-translate]: 2020-01-29T18:43:43Z Workflow "import-and-translate" finished cleanup.
[import-image] 2020/01/29 18:43:43 step "import" run error: step "wait-for-signal" run error: WaitForInstancesSignal FailureMatch found for "inst-importer-import-and-translate-import-0tnps": "ImportFailed: Failed to decode image file. When importing a VMDK disk image, ensure that you specify the VMDK disk image file, rather than its text descriptor file. In some virtual machine managers, given a text descriptor called <disk.vmdk>, the disk image file would be called <disk-flat.vmdk>.'"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/compute-image-tools/gce_vm_image_import:release" failed: exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your image is looking for some missing disks:
"/daisy-scratch/Ubuntu 64-bit-s001.vmdk"

Also you can see if your OS image is compatible with [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/compute-image-tools/tree/master/cli_tools/import_precheck/) tool.
I recommend you to check if you're importing all the correct disks.

Comment: I am only importing one file

Comment: Yes but you're importing an image, is that right? Maybe that image is looking for extra disks... do you still have the instance running or can you make it run in a virtualizer? So you can check if it has extra disks

Comment: No im importing a vm from my  omputer to gcp to use. I am using the make an image tool to do this

Comment: are you following any guide? maybe you'd need to contact support so you can share them more context and sensitive data, just use the billing chat and tell them.